# Are RSA and ECC certificates interchangeable?

Tags: encryption, certificate, openssl, rsa, cryptography

Can I use a ECC certificate if a service/software (according to documentation) requires an RSA certificate? Does the software need explicit ECC support?

Comment: They are NOT interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the certificate is used for, and whether there are non-technical requirements.

If the program doesn't do anything special, i.e. the certificate is simply given to a TLS library, and the TLS library *on both ends* is reasonably modern and supports ECC, then things should work fine.

But that's not always guaranteed – you might be dealing with older or space-limited code that only implements RSA, e.g. embedded devices, hardware tokens, etc. There are many smartcards and HSMs which only support RSA but not ECC. (And some products might support only P-256 but not P-384 (for example), or the other way around.)

Certificates are also used for other purposes besides TLS, and some of those might not be compatible with ECC – e.g. "dual purpose" sign+encrypt certificates in S/MIME are allowed for RSA but not ECC (per RFC 5480). Among non-TLS uses, things like digital signatures for firmware images, etc. might require RSA because that's what the bootloader was built to use.

Generally, if documentation says the service/software "requires" RSA, there's a reason such text was added to the documentation.